# Nondiagonalizable Matrix and Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I got the following problem:

If $A$ is a nondiagonalizable square matrix of order $n$ over field $\mathbb{F}$ then there exists a polynomial $P$ of degree $n-1$ over $\mathbb{F}$ such that $(P(A))^2=0$

 Over $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$ ?

 Over $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ ?

I tried to solve it but didn't manage to proceed that much.
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

For $\mathbb{C},$ $A$ nondiagonalizable means that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is of smaller degree than the characteristic polynomial, so at most $n-1,$ so you don't need to square - $P(A)=0,$ where $P$ is the minimal polynomial.

Comment: but the question says of degree $n-1$

Comment: Over $\mathbb{R}$ we can give a 2x2 example with characteristic polynomial $X^2 + 1$, which is not real diagonalizable.  This is also the minimal polynomial, and there is not polynomial of degree 1 which admits $(P(A))^2 = 0$.

Comment: But what is the case over $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: @hardmath precisely correct, I was trying to figure out what they were asking, but it does not make any sense.

Comment: @boris I don't understand the question: for a non-diagonalizable matrix the minimial polynomial is of degree $\leq n-1.$ If you want exactly $n-1,$ feel free to multiply the minimal polynomial by your favorite junk factor.

Comment: If the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial of a matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ are the same then the matrix is diagonalizable ? Where i can find the proof (if it's true)?

Comment: @JohnSaita check out: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/minimal.pdf